# How to share any variable/object between BDD scenarios with Cucumber and Java?

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

Here the login API call is common among all the scenarios, so I tried to use "Background". But in our case after login API call we get Session ID and this session ID needed to be passed as a header to all the calls happens after the Login call. Also Login call can not happen multiple time for the same user, so the login call should only happen for the one time and next calls should use only use the output of the login call happened first time.

Is there any in built technique in Cucumber BDD to handle this situation? I just do not want to write the same Login steps in each of the scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variable example:

```
public class Test{

public static final String NAME = "xpto"; // global}

System.out.println(Test.NAME);
```

With Ruby this is very easy:
We need add only @

```
    # steps1.rb
Given /^a person exists by the name of John Galt$/ do
  @person = Person.new
  @person.name = 'John Galt'
end

# steps2.rb
Then /^his name should be John Galt$/ do
  @person.name.should == 'John Galt'
end
```

Comment: Actually am searching for a solution in Java only

Comment: The firat solution is Java.